# Special character in LIKE in PostgreSQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have notifications table in my database which contains metadata field with data type TEXT.
Below is the one record for my notificaiton table

```
#<Notification id: 1863, target_type: "User", target_id: 8, object_type: nil, object_id: nil, read: true, metadata: {:title=>"test user sent you a message. Read it now!", :description=>"Dear user, You've received a new chat from test user. Tap here to check!", :notification_type=>"chat", :sender_id=>7, :receiver_id=>8, :name=>"Shyam fb", :img_url=>"http://s3-eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/moodit-prod/avatars/images/000/000/001/original/image.jpg"}, created_at: "2019-03-27 13:01:48", updated_at: "2019-03-27 13:05:03">
```

for one record metadata value is like below

```
metadata: {
           :title=>"test user sent you a message. Read it now!",
           :description=>"Dear user, You've received a new chat from test user. Tap here to check!", 
           :notification_type=>"chat", 
           :sender_id=>7, 
           :receiver_id=>8, 
           :name=>"Shyam fb", 
           :img_url=>"demo image url"
          }
```

I can get value 7 if i do

```
User.find(8).notifications.last.metadata[:sender_id]
```

I want find records for metadata which contains the string `sender_id=>7` .

I tried below queries but didn't get success

```
User.find(8).notifications.where("metadata LIKE ? ", "%#{sanitize_sql_like(:sender_id=>7)}%" )

User.find(8).notifications.where("metadata LIKE ? ESCAPE'=' ", "%sender_id=>7".gsub('=', '!=').gsub('>', '!>') + '%')

User.find(8).notifications.where("metadata LIKE LOWER(E'sender_id=>7%')")
```

How can i achieve that with LIKE query?

Comment: You can try with `ilike` operator in `postgresql`. This is case insensitive. It should be like `metadata ILIKE '%sender=>7%'`

Comment: I did it , but its also not working

Comment: Could you please try `User.find(8).notifications.where("metadata @> 'sender_id=>7'")` OR `User.find(8).notifications.where("metadata -> :key LIKE :value", key: "sender_id", value: "7")`, and I prefer using [Activerecord Store](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Store.html) for `metadata` to use JSON format as you are using PostgreSQL.

Comment: You must have implemented `serialize` with `json` option in your rails model. But in database, the data might not be saved exactly in that format. Please try to login to you `postgresql` console and query that notification record. Find out how that json data is saved in `postgresql`. It will help you to write `LIKE` statement for it

Comment: @Pavan for first query error is `ERROR:  operator does not exist: text @> unknown 
 HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.` for second query error is `ERROR:  operator does not exist: text -> unknown HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
`

Comment: @KrishnaRaniSahoo I am getting value if i do `User.find(8).notifications.last.metadata[:sender_id]`

Comment: @Pavan  I am getting value if i do 
 `User.find(8).notifications.last.metadata[:sender_id]`

Comment: You are referring the Rails code to get data. Rails will auto format the data to be readable in json format. You should query to `Postgresql` to get how the real data is stored in database. This will help you in querying a column.

Comment: @Pavan I am getting this error if i try this query `User.find(8).notifications.where("metadata::jsonb @> 'sender_id=>7'")`  `DETAIL:  Token "title" is invalid.
CONTEXT:  JSON data, line 1: title...
`

Comment: @KrishnaRaniSahoo  Can you check above error? if i check class of metadata field in rails console. it is giving me . hash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to make a query if anyone has this type of issue in future they can use below query for finding a record from the text data type.

```
User.find(8).notifications.where("position(':sender_id: ?' in metadata) != 0", 7)
```